# data transfer speed variation on baud rate

Tags: serial-port, baud-rate

I wanted to know if changing the baudrate of the serial channel  would bring a noticeable increase in the data transfer(say I change the baudrate from 9600 to 115200)?

I am confused because of the serial data transfer protocol.I doubt it would effect the transfer speed that is noticeable.

P.S. : 9600 * 12 = 115200

Comment: Yes, if you had a device printing long lines of text to a terminal, you could definitely see the difference between 9600 and 115200.  The 9600 lines would have visible latency whereas the 115200 lines would appear instantaneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, it generally will. All other things being equal and both ends are capable of running at the higher capacity, a faster bit rate will allow faster transfer speeds. That's why ADSL was better than 56K modems and why 100Mb/s LANs were better than 10Mb/s.

Now, that will be true as long as it's the bitrate that is the bottleneck. At some point, it will stop being the bottleneck and higher bitrates won't increase speed. Whether that happens *before* 115K depends on a lot of things.